# BeautifulSoup Parsing with Bad HTML Tables

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse tables similar to the following with BeautifulSoup to extract the name, age, and position for each person.

```
<TABLE width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

<TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="center" nowrap colspan="3"><FONT size="2"><B>Age as of</B></FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD align="center" nowrap><FONT size="2"><B>Name</B></FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="center" nowrap colspan="3"><FONT size="2"><B>November 1, 1999</B></FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="center" nowrap><FONT size="2"><B>Position</B></FONT></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD align="center" nowrap><HR size="1"></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="center" nowrap colspan="3"><HR size="1"></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="center" nowrap><HR size="1"></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    Terry S. Jacobs</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="right" valign="top" nowrap><FONT size="2">57</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    Chairman of the Board, Chief Executive Officer, Treasurer and
    director</FONT></TD>
</TR>

<TR><TD><TR><TD><TR><TD><TR><TD>

<TR>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    William L. Stakelin</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="right" valign="top" nowrap><FONT size="2">56</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    President, Chief Operating Officer, Secretary and director</FONT></TD>
</TR>

<TR><TD><TR><TD><TR><TD><TR><TD>

<TR>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    Joel M. Fairman</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="right" valign="top" nowrap><FONT size="2">70</FONT></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD align="left" valign="top"><FONT size="2">
    Vice Chairman and director</FONT></TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
```

My current attempt is as follows:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(in_file)
    out = []
    headers = soup.findAll(['td','th'])
    for header in headers:
        if header.find(text = re.compile(r"^age( )?", re.I)):
            out.append(header)
    table = out[0].find_parent("table")
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    filter_regex = re.compile(r'[\w][\w .,]*', re.I)
    data = [[td.find(text=filter_regex) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
```

Things work find for the first person, but the bad `<tr><td><tr><td>`... lines really mess things up from there. I am trying to do this for a few thousand HTML files, each having slightly different table structure. That said, this feature of `<tr>` and `<td>` tags not being closed appears quite common across the files.

Anyone have thoughts on how to generalize the above parsing to work with tables that have constructs such as these? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the `valign` attribute is set to `top` in all of the fields you'd like to keep and none of the ones you don't:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(in_file)
cells = [cell.text.strip() for cell in soup('td', valign='top')]
```

Then you can sort this list of cells into a two-dimensional structure. There are three cells per entry, so you can sort it out pretty simply by doing something like this:

```
entries = []
for i in range(0, len(cells), 3):
    entries.append(cells[i:i+3])
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been a bit clearer with the fact that I am using this parser on thousands of files with similar HTML tables. It's not clear that all of the table with have this attribute set like this so I was trying to be a bit more general with the code. Having extra `<tr>` and `<td>` tags without matching closing tags just seems common, so this was the example that I used.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess I'm still not sure exactly what the problem is, then. The point of BS is to correct sloppy HTML; it will close your unclosed `<tr>`s and `<td>`s automatically. The `<tr><td>`s will be normalized to `<tr><td></td></tr>`. If you don't want them, `filter` your list of rows, e.g. `filter(lambda row: len(row('td'))>1, soup('tr'))`. Maybe I'm still being unhelpful, in which case I do apologize.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be immediately closing the tags like this. It seems to be closing them at the end near the `</table>`. This results in the output having a huge repetition of names because of the nesting:

William L. Stakelin,William L. Stakelin,William L. Stakelin,William L. Stakelin,William L. Stakelin,57,"President, Chief Operating Officer, Secretary and director",Joel M. Fairman,Joel M. Fairman,Joel M. Fairman,Joel M. Fairman,Joel M. Fairman,70,Vice Chairman and director,Fred L. Murr... 

this is one entry of the output (it continues on for a bit past this).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Oh wow, that's not what I'm seeing at all. I tried it in bs4 and bs3 and got the same tidy tag closings, `<tr><td></td></tr>`. One thought: my `in_file` is exactly the HTML you provided above. If the actual file has a lot more to it, I'd imagine that would make a difference in how BS chooses to close the tags. Other than that I'm not sure what the issue could be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance anyone else get stuck with this issue and stumbles in here, the modern solution is to change which parser you are using.  The default parser, 'html.parser' is pretty good when working with close enough HTML with properly closed tags, but the second you have to deal with edge cases (like Example 1 below, which is similar to the OP issue), that still goes right out the window even 8 years later (example 2 below).

In the documentation for BeautifulSoup4 (current version 4.9.3), there is a section detailing parser selection: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Example 1, the raw HTML:

```
<TABLE >
  <TR VALIGN="top">
    <td>&nbsp;<td><b>Title:</b>
    <td>&nbsp;title is here <i>-subtitle</i><br>
  <TR VALIGN="top">
    <td>&nbsp;
    <td><b>Date:</b>
    <td>&nbsp;Thursday , August 27th, 2020
  <TR VALIGN="top">
    <td>&nbsp;<td><b>Type:</b>
    <td>&nbsp;61
  <TR VALIGN="top">
    <td>&nbsp;
    <td><b>Status:</b>
    <td>&nbsp;ACTIVE - ACTIVE
</TABLE>
```

Example 2, results when using `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`:

```
<table>
<tr valign="top">
<td> <td><b>Title:</b>
<td> title is here <i>-subtitle</i><br/>
<tr valign="top">
<td>
    <td><b>Date:</b>
<td> Thursday , August 27th, 2020
  <tr valign="top">
<td> <td><b>Type:</b>
<td> 61
  <tr valign="top">
<td>
    <td><b>Status:</b>
<td> ACTIVE - ACTIVE
</td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></tr></table>
```

Example 3, results when using `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')`:

```html
<table>
  <tbody><tr valign="top">
    <td> </td><td><b>Title:</b>
    </td><td> title is here <i>-subtitle</i><br/>
  </td></tr><tr valign="top">
    <td>
    </td><td><b>Date:</b>
    </td><td> Thursday , August 27th, 2020
  </td></tr><tr valign="top">
    <td> </td><td><b>Type:</b>
    </td><td> 61
  </td></tr><tr valign="top">
    <td>
    </td><td><b>Status:</b>
    </td><td> ACTIVE - ACTIVE
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

There are also parsers that are written externally in C such as 'lxml' that you could potentially use that is much faster according to the documentation.